# Preventing a class member conversion to JAXB XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, jaxb2

Here is my JAXB class,

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Status {

    private int code;
    private String message;

    public Status() {
    }

    public Status(int code, String message) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

I dont want the 'code' to be marshalled to XML. Here are the things I tried, but it always marshalled to XML.

- Annotate @XMLElement to only getMessage() method
- Make 'code' as transient

No hopes yet. The XMLAccessorType.NONE can be applied to class level. Not in element level. Please help.

Comment: The following post may help, it describes when to use `@XmlTransient` and when to use `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)`: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `@XmlTransient` annotation before the getter methods of the attributes you don't want to be marshalled.

Ex:

```
@XmlTransient
public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
```